# javascript load malfunction. Code works with Manual copy-paste, but not with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

This code seems to work, but only when i manually post the content inside class isotope from 1.php, to class grid of this page. If I use JS, God knows, why it stops working. Any Hints :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".grid").load("1.php .isotope > *");
});
</script>
<script>

$( function() {
  // init Isotope
  var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
itemSelector: '.element',
layoutMode: 'fitRows' ,
filter: '.lmd'
  });
  });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Isotope - filtering</h1>
<div class="grid"> </div>
<!--- /.grid --->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you use a debugger?

Comment: Dreamweaver m using. Its not showing any Errors.

Comment: I also debugged it using FireBug, but no success

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".grid").load("1.php .isotope > .class-wanted");
});
</script>
```